# How to catch fatal errors on page loading?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer with following options:

```
    {
        "headless": false,
        "args": [
            "--aggressive-cache-discard",
            "--disable-cache",
            "--disable-application-cache",
            "--disable-offline-load-stale-cache",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
            "--no-zygote",
            "--disable-gpu"
        ]
    }
```

Sometimes i got this page with error (screenshot), `page.on("error", error => {});` doesnt catch it.. how can i handle this issue?

[image]

**Steps to reproduce**

i dont know how to reproduce... randomly happens...

ps:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6330

upd:

```
        const browser = await require('puppeteer').launch(this.puppeteerOptions);
        const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await page.setDefaultTimeout(0);
        await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

        // TODO: handle restart browser/page
        page.on("error", error => {
            console.log(`${Date()} > got page error! ${error.message}`.red);
        });

        await page.goto(this.url);
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the whole code in a try catch block, and catch the error like that